# Why MAPI can't move all mail in folder?

Tags: python, outlook, pyzmq

I create zmq client python script for work with zmq server.It work all client well but when I create new mail folder for move finish works(client) to this folder. I use mail.Move function. It work some client. This's my client code:

```
import zmq
import json
import win32com.client
import time
import os
context = zmq.Context()
print('Connecting to manager approve server…')
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5555')
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("1.Manager")
donembox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("1.1done_manager")
outlook = inbox.Items
mail = outlook.GetLast()
for mail in outlook:
  if mail.Body == "Status: Manager Approved \r\n":
    print('Inv number : '+str(mail.Subject))
    socket.send_string(mail.Subject)
    message = socket.recv()
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Inv number : '+str(mail.Subject) + " was moved to AP approval Process.")
    time.sleep(1)
    mail.Move(donembox)
    print(str(mail.Subject)+ ' success.')
```

This's my zmq server code:

```
import time
import threading
import zmq
import win32com.client
import os, sys
import pyautogui as py
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind('tcp://*:5555')
print("Manager Server port 5555 Activate!")
while True:
  message = socket.recv()
  print('Received request: {}'.format(message))
  time.sleep(20)
  path = "R:/<my accounting team>/Project/Invoice form/Invoice_generate/"+str(message)+"/"+str(message)+".xlsm"
  isExist = os.path.exists(path) 
  print(isExist) 
  if os.path.exists(path):
      xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
      xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(path))
      xl.Application.Run("Module6.manager()")
      xl.Application.Quit()
      del xl
      time.sleep(2)
      py.click(599,392)
      time.sleep(2)
  socket.send_json({ 'status': 'ok' })
  print('Reply')
  print(path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are modifying (by calling `MailItem.Move`) the very collection you are processing, hence your code will skip some items.

Change the loop to a backward for loop (from `Items.Count` down to 1).